# Is array value as loop stop condition read every time?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, memory

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a[index]; i++) {
      // do stuff
}
```

Would `a[index]` be read every time? If no, what if someone wanted to change the value at `a[index]` in the loop? I've never seen it myself, but does the compiler make such an assumption?

If the condition was instead `i < val-2`, would it be evaluated every time?

Comment: It should be easy to write a test program that confirms this one way or the other.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You're right. But maybe someone has some interesting input as to why things are a specific way?

Comment: @user2864740 But is a[index] loaded at every iteration? And is val-2 is evaluated every time as well?

Comment: @UserNotDefined The "load" must occur every evaluation unless the compiler can absolutely guarantee that it cannot be modified elsewhere (or cause another side-effect): in the general case this is not possible. Even if such an optimization can be done it is entirely dependent on the compiler and flags used; looking at the output (-S flag for GCC) for a particular compiler will probably be useful here.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: That would actually just confirm that the code as generated by the compiler does (not) optimize away the access. But it would not be a valid general proof.

Comment: @Olaf: If compiler optimisation modifies behaviour, then either it's a broken compiler or undefined behaviour.  Either way, that would be a better question framing than the current "what would this code do if I ran it?"...

Comment: You can't guarantee it's going to be optimized if it can be, but you can guarantee it is not going to be optimized out if it can't be (i.e. if the condition can change during the loop). Anything else is compiler specific.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I agree, but as I understand the question, OP is actually asking _what_ is the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will perform optimizations normally when the system is not impacted by other parts of the program. So if you make changes inside the `for` loop on the condition parameter, the compiler will not optimize.

As mentioned, the compiler should read the array and check it before each iteration in your code snippet. You can optimize your code as follows, then it will read the array only once for loop condition checking.

```
int cond = a[index];
for (int i = 0; i < cond; i++) {
      // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the compiler have to also guarantee that aliasing does not occur?

Comment: @UserNotDefined it depends on the level of compiler optimizations choosing while we compile the code. http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html

Comment: @UserNotDefined: Yes.

Comment: @Steephen: Not really, no. Observable behaviour is defined by the standard and is not affected by implementation optimisation level (except for arguably copy ctor eliding). And your solution changes nothing — now the compiler just needs to figure out whether `cond` changes, instead of whether `a[index]` changes. Pretty pointless.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree with you. I read the OP's question in comment in a wide perspective, like how aliasing  going to impact  by compiler optimization

Answer (score 2):

**well, maybe.**

A standards compliant compiler will produce code that behaves as-if it
is read every time.

If `index` and/or `array` are of storage class `volatile` the they will be re-evaluated every time.

If they are not and the loops content doesn't use them in a way that can be expected to modify their value the optimiser may decide to use a cached result instead.

Comment: The class `volatile` is the only way to tell the compiler to reevaluate the expression each time. Other compiler behavior are not modifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Co does not store results of expressions in temporary variables. So, all expressions re evaluated in-place. Note that any `for` loop can be changed to a `while` loop:

```
for ( def_or_expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 ) {
    ...
}
```

becomes:

```
def_or_expr1;
while ( expr2 ) {
    ...
cont:
    expr3;
}
```

**Update:** `continue` in the `for` loop would be the same as `goto cont;` int the while loop above. I.e. `expr3` is evaluated for **every** iteration.

The compiler can bascially apply any optimization it can proof not to change the program's essence. Describing full details would be too far for this, but in general, it can (and will) optimize:

- `a[index]` is not changed in the loop: read once before loop and keep in a temp (e.g. register).
- `a[index]` is changed in the loop: update the temp (register) with the new value, avoiding memory access (and the index calculations).

For this, the compiler must assume the array is not changed outside the visible control flow. This is typically the file being compiled (with all included files). For modern systems using link time optimization (LTO), this can be the whole final program - minus dynamic libraries.

Note this is a very brief description. Actually, the C [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3) defines pretty clear how a program has to be executed, so what/how the compiler may optimize.

If the array is changed, for example by an interrupt handler or another thread, things become complicated. Depending on your target, you need from `volatile`, atomic operations (`stdatomic.h`, since C11) up to thread locks/mutexes/semapores/etc. to control accesses to the share resource.

Comment: `for` is not the same as `while` when the loop contains  `continue`

Comment: @Jasen: Thanks, I forgot about that. Updated.